# psexec and xcopy error 4

Tags: remote, pstools, xcopy

I am trying to use xcopy on a remote machine with psexec but i keep getting an error 4 and would love some brainstorming as to why that error might come up. The actual error says:
Invalid drive specification
0 File(s)
xcopy exited on 'remote machine' with error code 4

The command I am using is:
psexec \'remote machine' -u 'user' -p 'pass' xcopy 'source path of file' 'destination path'

Both file paths are located on the remote machine. I am typing the command on my local machine. Any advice or questions are very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: If you try the command locally on the target machine using the same credentials to log on does it work?

Comment: Have you tried using UNCs (maybe using the admin shares c$,d$) instead of local paths?

Comment: Are you copying files locally on the remote machine?  i.e.: copying from one local directory/drive to another?

Comment: Just to clarify some of your questions, it does work locally when the destination path is on my machine. The source path is a shared network drive and the destination path is a path located on the remote machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that error 4 [means](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t103354-process-problems-xcopy-exitcode.html): "Initialization error occurred.
There is not enough memory or disk space, or you entered an invalid drive
name or invalid syntax on the command line."

EDIT: Microsoft's [page on XCOPY](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: There is definitely enough space for the file and copy activity. I think that error is coming up because I am leaving something out maybe.

Comment: Replace xcopy with a batch file that echoes its arguments. Is what is printed what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed this after changing a few things. I made sure the parameters in the exact order as the psexec documentation and I added the domain in front of the username. I'm not sure exactly what fixed it, but it works now. Thanks for all the pointers, they taught me a lot.

Comment: You have to close the question, because it resurfaces on the top page, although you fixed the problem.

Comment: sorry, how do I do that?